# How can I add undeletable log to Devtools console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I will make a presentation online and I will use Chrome dev tools.
I want to add some useful information to myself and sometimes when I need to clear my console I want that information to remain there.

For example, when I click the clear console button I want certain logs to stay there. Is this possible?

[image: Devtools]

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not possible to create an "undeletable log", you can override `console.clear`'s default behavior to clear the console but log the message again:

```js
var log = console.clear;

const message = 'Hi!'

console.clear = function(e) {
  log.apply();
  console.log(message)
};

console.log(message)

console.log('Hello')
console.clear()
```

Comment: Idea is great to thank you for that but when I ran your solution log disappears and not coming back

Comment: @OrhanÖzkerçin Where are you running it?

Comment: I tried on snippet with full screen and I run in my project if that is what you are asking

Comment: @OrhanÖzkerçin Try running it in your project. Running with the snippet full screen won't work, since the JS is confined to the snippet's iframe.

Comment: I added to my project still same. Here is the gif: 
 https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Animationad960ba2ba96043d.gif

Comment: @OrhanÖzkerçin This solution will only work for `console.clear`. There's no actual way to prevent a determined user from hiding the log.

Comment: Oh, now I get it.  I really worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what about e.g. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference#persist

cited: "Persist messages across page loads

By default the Console clears whenever you load a new page. To persist messages across page loads, Open Console Settings and then enable the Preserve Log checkbox."

Will it help?

Comment: OP wants the log to persist after clearing the console.